# Get all parent and store them in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form class="register">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn btn-submit" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group needAccount" id="req_val">
        <a href="#" class="toggleForms">Login from here</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now I want to traverse this form and get all parents of last `div#req_val`, so the output should be a string i.e.

```
form.register div.form-group.needAccount#req_val
```

Comment: div#req_val has only one parent in given code. Explain your question clearly and what you have tried to get the output.

Comment: Actually I'm working on html dom crawler in php, I need to select elements from users and then grab html of selected elements. That's why I want All parents of clicked elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse through the parents using `.parents()` and generate it yourself. See a sample implementation below:

```
// returns <tag-name>[.<class1>[.<class2>] ...][#<id>] for the passed element
function getSelector(_elem) {
    var parts = [_elem.tagName].concat(_elem.className.split(/\s+/).map(function(_class) {
        return (_class ? '.' + _class : '');
    }));
    _elem.id && parts.push('#' + _elem.id);
    return parts.join('');
}

var elem = $('#req_val'), parents = elem.parents(), str = [];
parents.each(function() { // add parents
   str.unshift(getSelector(this)); // unshift since parents() gives you the nearest parent first
});
str.push(getSelector($('#req_val')[0])); // add self
str = str.join(' '); // join with space

console.log(str);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wu41vwuf/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parents()` or `.parentsUntil()` (if you need to stop at the form).

As `.parents()` does not include the current element itself, you need to `.add()` it to the resulting set. Then `.map()` thru the set and create a string which you want for each element in the set. Use `.get()` to get DOM elements out of the jQuery set and then `.join()` them to a string.

In the below snippet I have included one more `div` around the `form` so that you know how `.parents()` is traversing the tree.

***Snippet:***

```js
var $parents = $("#req_val").parents().add("#req_val");
var str = $parents.map(function () {
    var retVal = this.tagName;
    retVal += this.id ? '#' + this.id : '';
    retVal += this.className ? '.' + this.className.replace(' ', '.') : '';
    return retVal;
}).get().join(' ');

$("#result").text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form class="register">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn btn-submit" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group needAccount" id="req_val"> <a href="#" class="toggleForms">Login from here</a>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<hr />
<p id="result"></p>
```